# Product of fibrations is a fibration in a fibration category

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ a category with a class of fibrations and weak equivalence such that

1. The category $\mathcal{C}$ has a terminal object $1$ and all maps $X\to 1$ are fibrations
2. Pullbacks of fibrations exist and are fibrations again
3. Pullbacks of acyclic fibrations are acyclic fibrations
4. Weak equivalences satisfy 2-out-of-3
5. Fibrations are closed under composition
6. Every map $f:X\to Y$ factorizes as a weak equivalence followed by a fibration
7. Isomorphisms are acyclic fibrations

I am trying to show that given to maps $f_1:X_1\to Y_1$ and $f_2:X_2\to Y_2$ are fibrations, the product $f_1\times f_2:X_1\times X_2 \to Y_1\times Y_2$ is a fibration. It suffices to show this for the product of a fibration $f:X\to Y$ with the identity $1_Z:Z\to Z$ for some $Z$. I have tried a few things but nothing worked out yet, it shouldn't be that hard I think, but I can't get it to work.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $p:E\rightarrow B$ be a fibration. Given any object $X$ form the product $X\times B$ as the pullback of the cospan $X\rightarrow \ast\leftarrow B$. Observe that the following square is a pullback
\begin{array}{ccc}
X\times E &\xrightarrow{pr_2} & E \\
\ {1_X\times p}\downarrow & &\ \downarrow p\\
X\times B &\xrightarrow{pr_2} &B.
\end{array}
From the axioms we get that $1_X\times p:X\times E\rightarrow X\times B$ is a fibration. Similar reasoning shows that $p\times 1_X:E\times X\rightarrow B\times X$ is a fibration.

Now let $p_i:E_i\rightarrow B_i$, $i=1,2$, be fibrations and factor $p_1\times p_2$ as
$$p_1\times p_2:E_1\times E_2\xrightarrow{1_{E_1}\times p_2}E_1\times B_2\xrightarrow{p_1\times 1_{B_2}}B_1\times B_2.$$
Since a composition of fibrations is a fibration we get that $p_1\times p_2$ is a fibration.